# How can I compose an Entity Framework query from smaller, resusable queries?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, composition

I have a few (fairly redundant) queries in my app that are something like this:

```
var last30Days = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);

from b in Building
let issueSeverity = (from u in Users
                     where u.Building == b
                     from i in u.Issues
                     where i.Date > last30Days
                     select i.Severity).Max()
select new
{
    Building = b,
    IssueSeverity = issueSeverity
}
```

And:

```
var last30Days = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);

from c in Countries
let issueSeverity = (from u in Users
                     where u.Building.Country == c
                     from i in u.Issues
                     where i.Date > last30Days
                     select i.Severity).Max()
select new
{
    Country = c,
    IssueSeverity = issueSeverity
}
```

This is a simplified example, of course.  However, the gist is that I need to capture a date and filter a subquery on it.  I also need to filter the subquery differently based on the parent object.

I tried (essentially) creating the following function:

```
public IQueryable<int?> FindSeverity(Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate)
{
    var last30Days = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);

    return from u in Users.Where(predicate)
           from i in u.Issues
           where i.Date > last30Days
           select i.Severity;
}
```

Using it as follows:

```
from c in Countries
let issueSeverity = FindSeverity(u => u.Building.Country == c).Max()
select new
{
    Country = c,
    IssueSeverity = issueSeverity
}
```

This compiles, but does not work at runtime.  Entity frameworks complains about the `FindSeverity` function being unknown.

I've tried a few different methods of Expression gymnastics, but to no avail.

What do I need to do to compose reusable Entity Framework queries?

Comment: = everywhere instead of =='s? Typo?

Answer (score 2):

I've played around a bit with your problem but without a final satisfying result. I will only list the few points I could find and understand.

**1)**

I rewrite your last code snippet (in simplified form without the projection to an anonymous type)...

```
var query = from c in Countries
            select FindSeverity(u => u.Building.Country == c).Max();
```

...and then in extension method syntax:

```
var query = Countries
            .Select(c => FindSeverity(u => u.Building.Country == c).Max());
```

Now we see better that `FindSeverity(u => u.Building.Country == c).Max()` is the **body** of an `Expression<Func<Country, T>>` (`T` is `int` in this case). (I'm not sure if "body" is the correct terminus technicus, but you know what I mean: the part right from the Lambda arrow =>). When the whole query is translated into an expression tree this body is translated as a method call to the function `FindSeverity`. (You can see this in the debugger when you watch the `Expression` property of `query`: `FindSeverity` is directly a node in the expression tree, and not the body of this method.) This fails on execution because LINQ to Entities doesn't know this method. In the body of such a lambda expression you can only use known functions, for instance the canonical functions from the static `System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions` class.

**2)**

A possible general way to build reusable parts of a query is to write custom extension methods of `IQueryable<T>`, for example:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<int?> FindSeverity(this IQueryable<User> query,
                                       Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate)
    {
        var last30Days = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);

        return from u in query.Where(predicate)
               from i in u.Issues
               where i.Date > last30Days
               select i.Severity;
    }
}
```

Then you can write queries like:

```
var max1 = Users.FindSeverity(u => u.Building.ID == 1).Max();
var max2 = Users.FindSeverity(u => u.Building.Country == "Wonderland").Max();
```

As you can see, you are forced to write your queries in extension method syntax. I don't see a way to use such custom query extension methods in query syntax.

The example above is only a general pattern to create reusable query fragments but it doesn't really help for the specific queries in your question. At least I don't know how to reformulate your `FindSeverity` method so that it fits into this pattern.

**3)**

I believe that your original queries cannot work in LINQ to Entities. A query like this...

```
from b in Building
let issueSeverity = (from u in Users
                     where u.Building == b
                     from i in u.Issues
                     where i.Date > last30Days
                     select i.Severity).Max()
select new
{
    Building = b,
    IssueSeverity = issueSeverity
}
```

...falls under the category ["Referencing a non-scalar variable"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896317.aspx#RefNonScalarClosures) inside of a query which is not supported in LINQ to Entities. (In LINQ to Objects it works.) The non-scalar variable in the query above is `Users`. If the `Building` table is not empty an exception is expected: *"Unable to create a constant value of type EntityType. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context."*

It looks that you have a one-to-many relationship between `User` and `Building` in the database but this association isn't completely modelled in your Entities: `User` has a navigation property `Building` but `Building` doesn't have a collection of `Users`. In this case I would expect a `Join` in the query, something like:

```
from b in Building
join u in Users
  on u.Building.ID equals b.ID
let issueSeverity = (i in u.Issues
                     where i.Date > last30Days
                     select i.Severity).Max()
select new
{
    Building = b,
    IssueSeverity = issueSeverity
}
```

This wouldn't create the mentioned exception of referencing a non-scalar variable. But perhaps I misunderstood your model.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I may end up having to build up the entire expression tree manually...