# combine two expressions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am trying to create an expression for using in entity framework query.
I created two expressions:

```
public Expression<Func<IEntityPriceDefinition, bool>> IsMatchExpression(long additionId)
    {
        return x => x.PriceDefinition.AdditionsPrices.Any(a => a.AdditionId == additionId);
    }
public Expression<Func<IEntityPriceDefinition, bool>> IsMatchExpression(
    long? inviterId, long? routeId, long? luggageTypeId)
{
    return x =>
        (inviterId.HasValue || routeId.HasValue || luggageTypeId.HasValue) &&
        !(
            (x.PriceDefinition.InviterId.HasValue && inviterId.HasValue &&
                PriceDefinition.InviterId.Value != inviterId.Value) ||

            (PriceDefinition.LuggageTypeId.HasValue && luggageTypeId.HasValue &&
                PriceDefinition.LuggageTypeId.Value != luggageTypeId.Value) ||

            (PriceDefinition.InviterId.HasValue && inviterId.HasValue &&
                PriceDefinition.InviterId.Value != inviterId.Value)
        );
}
```

And now I am willing to combine them:

```
    public Expression<Func<IEntityPriceDefinition, bool>> IsMatchExpression(
        long? inviterId, long? routeId, long? luggageTypeId, long additionId)
    {
        return IsMatchExpression(inviterId, routeId, luggageTypeId) &&
                IsMatchExpression(additionId);
    }
```

This method doesn't compiles. I also have the feeling I did something wrong. How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**
I forgotenn importent part! the question updated.

Comment: @Nicolas78: I need to create expression that will combine both expressions.

Comment: ah ok. well what you're writing here evaluates both expressions and tries to return true or false depending on whether both are met. maybe you can say a bit about these MatchExpressions and about your use case so we can better help you.

Comment: @Nicolas78: You right - I forgotten importent thing and I fixed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just created combined method:

```
   public Expression<Func<IEntityPriceDefinition, bool>> IsMatchExpression(
        long? inviterId, long? routeId, long? luggageTypeId, long additionId)
    {
    return x =>
        (inviterId.HasValue || routeId.HasValue || luggageTypeId.HasValue) &&
        (x.PriceDefinition.AdditionsPrices.Any(a => a.AdditionId == additionId)) &&
        !(
            (x.PriceDefinition.InviterId.HasValue && inviterId.HasValue &&
                PriceDefinition.InviterId.Value != inviterId.Value) ||

            (PriceDefinition.LuggageTypeId.HasValue && luggageTypeId.HasValue &&
                PriceDefinition.LuggageTypeId.Value != luggageTypeId.Value) ||

            (PriceDefinition.InviterId.HasValue && inviterId.HasValue &&
                PriceDefinition.InviterId.Value != inviterId.Value)
        );
}
```

Not the best solution but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to work with the expression components directly to do this.

```
public Expression<Func<IEntityPriceDefinition, bool>> IsMatchExpression(
        long? inviterId, long? routeId, long? luggageTypeId, long additionId)
{
    var a = IsMatchExpression(inviterId, routeId, luggageTypeId);
    var b = IsMatchExpression(additionId);
    var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEntityPriceDefinition),"x");
    var c = Expression.AndAlso(Expression.Invoke(a,p),Expression.Invoke(b,p));
    var r = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEntityPriceDefinition, bool>>(c,p);
    return r;
}
```

This could be made more sophisticated by breaking out the `.Body` from each of the two expressions and replacing (using an `ExpressionVisitor`) the parameters with the new parameter; and each of your two working methods could be changed to bind their parameters into `ConstantExpression`s, losing the lambda expression syntax altogether. Those changes may in fact be necessary to make an expression that can work properly with entity framework, but this will take some time for me to work out to post in the answer.

See also [How can I compose an Entity Framework query from smaller, resusable queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782453/how-can-i-compose-an-entity-framework-query-from-smaller-resusable-queries)

Comment: It created an exception: Expression of type 'System.Func`2[IEntityPriceDefinition,System.Boolean]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Boolean'.

Comment: Where it tried to make lambda from it: var r = Expression.Lambda<Func<IEntityPriceDefinition, bool>>(c,p);

Comment: Meanwhile I marked an answer. If you have an idea - I'll be here to listen. Thanks!

Comment: @Naor: I finally had time to look at this, and I got no error. Did you change something in the method?

Answer (score 0):

ok could it be sth like

```
var x = IsMatchExpression(inviterId, routeId, luggageTypeId)
var y = IsMatchExpression(additionId);
return arg => x(arg) && y(arg)
```

?

Comment: you might need some additional syntactic voodoo, I'm not familiar with the Expression interface; the point however is the difference between calling those functions within the function vs return a lambda function which will call there return values later on

Comment: this is not working. I believe I am using wrong the Expression interface. I am not sure this is the way of creating expressions for entity framework queries.

Comment: in this line: "return arg => x(arg) && y(arg);" I get "x is a variable but used like a method".  I believe this is not the way and I need to build an expression tree but I don't know how to start.